# Separating a line of text into two arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm writing a translating program given a text file of english-language conversion. Each line of text will look something like

> hello;hola
>
> goodbye;adiós

I want to separate the two words into two different char arrays

> char[] eng;
>
> char[] span;

Right now I have to read in the file and store each word in the arrays

```
 int currentChar;
 while( currentChar != EOF ) {

    fscanf(inFile, "%[^;]c, %c", eng, span);

    printf("%s", eng);
    currentChar = fgetc( inFile );


}`
```

When I print out eng, it gives me back both words but no ; so the output looks like

> hellohola
>
> goodbyeadiós

I'm new to C so any sort of tips will help

Comment: the declaration of a char array is: `char eng[MAX_NUM_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN]`    Not `char[] eng;`    `

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you can modify the fscanf line like so:

```
fscanf(inFile, "%[^;];%s", eng, span);
```

You will still have to think about possible buffer overflows or malformed input lines, though.

Comment: 1) By not using something like `"%99[^;];%99s"`, code is prone to buffer overrun like  `gets()`  2) By not accounting the trailing `'\n'`, the next `eng` will likely begin with `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for, and at the least will give you an idea of how to use the fscanf format string given the input format you provided. You will also need to add logic to prevent buffer overruns.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getTwoLanguages(FILE *inFile, char **language1, char **language2);

int main()
{
    char *en[1024], *sp[1024];
    int i;

    // Get the phrase pairs
    getTwoLanguages(stdin, en, sp);

    // Output
    for (i = 0; en[i] && sp[i]; i++)
        printf("%s <-> %s\n", en[i], sp[i]);

    // Cleanup
    for (i = 0; en[i]; i++)
        free(en[i]);
    for (i = 0; sp[i]; i++)
        free(sp[i]);

    return 0;
}

void getTwoLanguages(FILE *inFile, char **language1, char **language2)
{
    char working1[256], working2[256];
    while (!feof(inFile)
        && fscanf(inFile, "%[^;\n\r]%*[;\n\r]%[^;\n\r]%*[;\n\r]", working1, working2) == 2)
    {
        /* Save the token and NULL the next one to indicate EOL */
        *language1++ = strdup(working1);
        *language1 = NULL;
        *language2++ = strdup(working2);
        *language2 = NULL;
    }
}
```